# How to pass a value in jQuery

Tags: jquery

I want to pass an error message. How do I do it and what do I need to change?

```
    success: function(data) {
      var div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'message').html(data.message);
      if (data.success == 0) {
        $.modaldialog.error('The operation failed.');

        ...
```

I want to replace the `div` with the error message that comes into this success function. I still need the id though I think because it is what toggles between the success and error block.

---

'The operation failed.' should be replaced with the error message that is contained in 'data.message'.

Comment: Where do you want to pass the error message?  I don't understand what is being passed and where it is being passed to.

Comment: slifty, I've added an explanation above. thanks.

Answer (score 1):

"'The operation failed.' should be replaced with the error message that is contained in 'data.message'"

```
 success: function(data){
    var div = $('<div>').attr('id', 'message').html(data.message);
    if(data.success == 0){
      $.modaldialog.error(data.message);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
if(data.success == 0){
          $.modaldialog.error(div);
```

??